# Where is the endianness of the frame buffer device accounted for?

Tags: linux-kernel, framebuffer

I'm working on a board with an at91 sama5d3 based device. In order to test the framebuffer, I redirected a raw data file to /dev/fb0. The file was generated using gimp and exported as a raw data file in the 'normal RGB' format. So as a serialised byte stream the data format in the file is RGBRGB (where each colour is 8 bits).

When copied to the framebuffer, the Red and the Blues were swapped as the LCD controller operates in little endian format when configured for 24 bpp mode.

This got me wondering, at what point is the endianness of the framebuffer taken into account? I'm planning on using directfb and had a look at some of the docs but didn't see anything directly alluding to the endianness of the pixel data.

I'm not familiar with how the kernel framebuffer works and so am missing a few pieces of the puzzle.

Comment: What is the driver in use? **fbtft**?

Comment: The platform driver is the atmel-hlcdc-display-controller which is a drm device (not sure if I'm answered  your question)

Comment: Would it be hardware issue, like connection between LCD matrix and controller?

Comment: I only know this via python but... You can query the framebuffer for format information `ioctl(fbhandle, FBIOGET_VSCREENINFO, bytes(160))` and `FBIOGET_FSCREENINFO`. The response will indicate Truecolor and provide a pixel format, the RGB offsets, size and endianness. As well as  rotation, panning, etc. Note that eg in 16bpp mode, colours can cross byte-boundaries (eg bits `RRRRRGGG|GGGBBBBB`). See [https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/fb/api.txt](kernel.org) for a good overview, and [http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/uapi/linux/fb.h](Linux Cross Reference) for the header files.